# How to plot multiple numpy array in one figure?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I know how to plot a single numpy array

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(np.array)
```

But is there any way to plot multiple numpy array in one figure? I know `plt.subplots()` can display multiple pictures. But it seems hard in my case. I have tried to use a `for` loop.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(10):
   ax.imshow(np.array)  # i_th numpy array
```

This seems to plot a single numpy array one by one. Is there any ways to plot all my 10 numpy arrays in one figure?

PS: Here each my 2d numpy array represents the pixel of a picture. `plot` seems to plot lines which is not suitable in my case.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to see as the end result. Do your 10 arrays have the same dimensions? If so: what is your desired result after plotting these 10 arrays 'together'? If you keep plotting the newest array will simply overlap the others.

Comment: @stfwn Yes, they are the same dimension. My desired result would be a three rows of figs. Number of figs in each row are 4,4,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `plt.subplots()` [(here)](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) specifies that it takes an `nrows` and `ncols` arguments and returns a `fig` object and an array of `ax` objects. For your case this would look like this:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 4)
```

`axs` now contains a 2D array filled with `ax` objects that you can use to plot various things, e.g. `axs[0,1].plot([1,2],[3,4,])` would plot something on the first row, second column.

If you want to remove a particular `ax` object you can do that with `.remove()`, e.g. `axs[0,1].remove()`.

For `.imshow` it works in exactly the same way as `.plot`: select the ax you want and call `imshow` on it.

A full example with simulated image data for your case would be:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 4)
images = [np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]) for _ in range(10)]
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flatten()):
    if i < len(images):
        ax.imshow(images[i])
    else:
        ax.remove()
plt.show()
```

With as the result:

[image]

Comment: OP doesn't want to plot in different subplots. OP wants to overlay multiple arrays over the same figure

Comment: Sorry for this ignoring an important information.  My numpy array here represents the pixel of a picture(shape of numpy array is 128*128). I have tried to use axs.plt, it plots lines. I think I still need to use plt.imshow to display the picture.

Comment: For `imshow` it works the same as it does for `plot`. I edited my answer to show a full example.